# Add comment to a post - NoReverseMatch error

Tags: django, django-templates, django-urls

I am building a website with a simple blog.
I follow the instructions from: http://lightbird.net/dbe/blog.html
I got to a point where I see posts, but then he adds links to each post.
I added :

```
(r"^(\d+)/$", "post"),
```

to my `urls.py` and when I added : `<a href="{% url 'news.views.post post.pk' %}">Comments</a>` everything breaks. It's like it's not sending the value. I think I am doing something wrong with the links..

Can anyone check my app?
Admin account : admin/admin. 
Wrong code is in: templates/news/list.html
When I delete that line it works.

Here is my code: https://db.tt/b7qpib28

TRACEBACK : http://dpaste.com/1471932/

Comment: What django version is this? You definitely use url tag the wrong way. Try: `{% url 'news.views.post' post.pk %} Notice different quote position.

Comment: Ok not it gets the id, but still an error "Reverse for 'news.views.post' with arguments '(5,)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found."

Comment: I think there is a problem with my urls.py in news/urls.py Can you check that, please? Is "(r"^(\d+)/$", post)" a correct line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to remove the `$` in url pattern that includes `news.urls`, so in `Uploader/uploader/uploader/urls.py` change the line 32:

```
(r"^news/$", include('news.urls')),
```

by this

```
(r"^news/", include('news.urls')),
```

That's all ;)  ...this obstruct the rest of url, you can display the url for news.views.main because it didn't add anything to the url but news.views.post need to add the pk parameter

Comment: I assume that you have done the correction proposed by @Alasdair which not solve the problem but need to be fixed

Comment: I've spent (literally) hours on this and it turned out to be a matter of one character. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, your closing single quote is I the wrong place. Secondly, try using the url pattern name instead of the path to the view.

Try the following:

```
{% url 'post' post.pk %}
```

Comment: Can you check that at my app? I provided the link. I tried it and it still gives the same error: "Reverse for 'post' with arguments '(5,)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found."

Comment: No, I'm afraid I can't download your app on this device. I hope you figure out what the problem is.

Comment: I added a traceback in my first post - maybe that will help you? I still get the same error, I think the links are wrong.